# what is the mysql query to perform frequency ranking

Tags: mysql

am looking for a query which will perform frequency ranking, so that the record which has maximum occurances of supplied "key word" will be listed top in the result.

my fields in the table are text and id.
Can any one help me in this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Really need more info.  Your question asks for max occurrences of supplied key word, but what does that have to do with the columns named (text and id).  Is "key word" included in the text?  Is "key word" equal to text?  Is this what you mean: "I want a query that shows the records in order by the number of times that "keyword" appears in the text column?"

Comment: My column "text"has just some textual data in which i have to search for given key word.Ya you got my question right.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:  replace the keyword with nothing, then compare the new size to the old size.  The difference, divided by the length of the keyword, is equal to the number of times it was found.

```
select id, text, 
    (length(text)-length(replace(text, 'KEYWORD', '')))/length('KEYWORD') 
from TableName 
where text like '%KEYWORD%';
```

This seems kind of flaky to me, but since you are trying to do it with SQL I could not think of a SQL string comparison function that returns the number of times a string was found.

Comment: If i am looking for a word 'bar' the above query will match 'barred','barb' which i dont want.Actually am using rails for my application , is there better alternative in rails?any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Instead of just looking at 'KEYWORD',  could you look for ' KEYWORD ' (that is, with spaces around it)?  Are you looking at a series of words, a text document, or what?  As for a rails answer, I can't help you there.

Comment: My column text is of mysql type text,which is a series of text which may span for 1000 words or more for few cases.
if i use ' bar ' then no records are retrieved even if its there in the table. 
i found another query in one mysql forum which is
 SELECT id, text, MATCH (text) AGAINST ('keyword') AS score FROM contents WHERE MATCH (text) AGAINST ('keyword') INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/bar1.txt';
this query works fine for other keywords like hopsital,but for bar its not giving any records,dont know what is the reason.

Comment: But the problem with query i mentioned is, if am searching for hopsital then records with Hospital (multiple times)is not given high score.how do i make the query case insensitive. will adding IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE will help (it is available only in mysql 5.1  right,but i have 5.0.67.do i have to upgrade?)